# React Native Charts for android

Tags: android, graph, charts, react-native

Hi can someone suggest me the best way to implement charts in react native , I have already implemented the chart for iOS using https://github.com/onefold/react-native-chart and it works fine , but for android i am struggling a little bit , if somebody can , that will be a great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using this library https://github.com/hongyin163/react-native-chart-android.
It does the job for Android.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 nice libraries for creating charts in react-native for both platforms iOS and android, take a look:

> 1. react-native-svg-charts at: https://github.com/JesperLekland/
> 2. react-native-chart-kit at: github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit –

You also could look at Animated Charts in React Native using D3 and ART. With these 2 libraries you will able make customisation graphs and even animate them. 
[Link for tutorial](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/animated-charts-in-react-native-using-d3-and-art-21cd9ccf6c58)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper.

Support both android and ios. Use latest MpAndroidChart and Charts

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `react-native-chart-kit` & `react-native-svg`. Just install it, import & you can draw several type of charts, such us: line, bezier line, progress, bar, pie chart & contribution graph (heat map). You can try my basic project: [click here](https://github.com/LintangWisesa/ReactNative_ChartKit). Enjoy